# Why it is showing invalid arguments passed with response_code 502?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using railway api to display the  train-live status .
But on running on server it send response_code 502,which means "invalid arguments passed".
What is the problem with form fields variables I am using?
I am using my api in place of my-Api-key.

```js
var express=require('express');
const app=express();
var fs=require('fs');
var path=require('path'); 
var url=require('url');
var request=require('request');
var https=require('https');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/live',function(req,res){
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/live-train.html'));
});


app.post('/Status',function(req,res){
 request({
  url:'https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/live/train/'+req.body.tnum+'/station/'+req.body.stnCode+'/date/'+req.body.date+'/apikey/<my-Api-key>/',json:true
 },function(error,response,body){
  if(error){throw error;}
      console.log(JSON.stringify(body,undefined,2));
     
 });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Live-Status</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="/Status" method="post">
    Train No:<input type="text" name="tnum" required><br>
    Station Code:<input type="text" name="stnCode" required><br>
    Date:<input type="date" name="date"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="submit">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. It seems to be working ok for me. Can you post what `console.log(JSON.stringify(body, undefined, 2))` comes back with (but put that line at the beginning of the `app.post` function.

Comment: {
  "station": {
    "code": null,
    "name": null,
    "lat": null,
    "lng": null
  },
  "train": {
    "classes": [],
    "number": null,
    "days": [],
    "name": null
  },
  "debit": 0,
  "response_code": 502,
  "status": {
    "has_departed": null,
    "actdep": null,
    "actarr_date": null,
    "latemin": null,
    "scharr": null,
    "scharr_date": null,
    "has_arrived": null,
    "actarr": null,
    "schdep": null
  },
  "start_date": null,
  "position": null
}

Comment: the above is output generated on console

Comment: I see. However, that's the response from Railway. Can you please move the `console.log` line at the beginning of your `app.post` function so we can see what came into _your_ api?

Comment: app.post('/Status',function(req,res){
 console.log(body);
 request({
  url:'https://api.railwayapi.com/v2/live/train/'+req.body.tnum+'/station/'+req.body.stnCode+'/date/'+req.body.date+'/apikey/skpbo00s3d/',json:true
 },function(error,response,body){
  if(error){throw error;}
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(body,undefined,2));
     
 });
});   output is=====ReferenceError: body is not define

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention to change `console.log(body)` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))`. Can you please make that change and let us know what the output is?

Comment: I solved it .The problem is with date format ,the html  form give date in 'DD-MM-YYYY ' format while the js file send the date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format so the problem is happend.

Comment: Interesting. Cool, glad to hear you solved it.